# How to use a formula as a reference inside a formula in Microsoft Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel

I want to use something like this
=VLOOKUP((=LEFT(I79,4)),'Network Prefixes List'!A2:B78, 2, FALSE )

Comment: Remove the "=" before "LEFT"

Comment: Thank you it worked.

Comment: How about this one
Example:
I want the cell to look up a condition
If Smart/TNT = +3 to the amount located before that cell
and if Globe/TM = +2
and if etc = +10


If amount is located at C2 the output would be located at D2

If the value in C2 is 10 and it checks H2 what condition it satisfies and like 
f it is Smart/TNT then the output will be 13 
if it is Globe/TM the output should be 12 
if it is etc then the output will be 20

Comment: If you have a new question, please don't put it here in the comments. Create a new question. However, you're unlikely to get much assistance with your follow-up question in its current form. You should include your spreadsheet layout and the formula that is not working the way you expect.

Answer (score 1):

Modify the formula to:

```
=VLOOKUP(LEFT(I79,4),'Network Prefixes List'!A2:B78,2,FALSE)
```

Comment: While this is more characters than [Mike Fitzpatrick’s answer](https://superuser.com/q/1609955/150988#1609968), it is less clear and less general — and therefore less useful.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the "=" before "LEFT"